# MVC implementation with .Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, webserver, deploying

I have implement MVC1 with one of domain www.onlinegk.in it is working fine when I am running it in local machine, but when I am deploying it in my webserver  it's action link is not working, getting the error message 404 Page Not Found. Any body can help me to short out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Your question title specifies mvc 2 and your question body specifies mvc 1 ... please clarify :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are about 10^6 reasons why your code is not working. And because you haven't shown your code we can only be guessing. So my guess is that you have hardcoded the url somewhere instead of using url helpers. For example you wrote:

```
<a href="/foo/bar">Bar</a>
```

instead of:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Bar", "bar", "foo") %>
```

or you had some javascript:

```
$('foo').load('/foo/bar');
```

instead of:

```
$('#foo').load('<%= Url.Action("bar", "foo") %>');
```

and this list goes on until we exhaust the 10^6 possibilities of why your code is working locally and not when deployed.